# How to find a record from a repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I find a record from a repository in the controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ShopMyShopBundle:Product')->find($value);
```

Can I do something like this in template ?

```
{{ em.name }}
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: What do you know? hot to pass data from repositories to templates?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what is in `$value`. Method `find()` will finb by `id`. If you want to search by for example `slug`, you have to call method `findBySlug()` or equivalent `findOneBySlug()`.

Answer (score 0):

In a controller:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$product = $em->getRepository('ShopMyShopBundle:Product')->find($value);
```

You can not do this in template. Feel free to read [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database).